# How to use Spark's .newAPIHadoopFile() in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to read na `lzo` file in spark job.
My spark version is `1.6.0` (spark-core_2.10-1.6.0-cdh5.7.1).

Here is my java code:

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("ReadLzo"));
JavaPairRDD <NullWritable, Text> lines = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(args[0],LzoTextInputFormat.class,NullWritable.class,Text.class,new Configuration());
```

But I am getting a compile time exception:

> The method newAPIHadoopFile(String, Class, Class, Class,
>   Configuration) in the type JavaSparkContext is not applicable for the
>   arguments (String, Class, Class,
>   Class, Configuration)

So what is the correct way to use `JavaSparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile()` in Java?

Comment: What types are the generics F,  K, and V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No guarantees, but `LzoTextInputFormat` extends `TextInputFormat`, whose Key is `LongWritable` and value is `Text`.

Make sure your import statements are of the correct types as well. Especially for `Text`

Comment: thanks @cricket_007  I changed key class from `NullWritable` to `LongWritable` it worked.